# How to draw x^(2/3) as a tikxpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, axis

I've tried the following code, but the part with negative x doesn't get drawn

```
 \begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty,
            xlabel={$t$},xlabel style={anchor=east},
            ylabel={$f(x)=x^{2/3}$},ylabel style={anchor=north}]
            \addplot[-] expression[domain=-1:1,samples=1000]{x^(2/3)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: A fractional power of a negative number usually has a nontrivial imaginary part, so it is hard to plot.

Comment: So how can I draw that function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update** As it seems that my first redaction was wrong or at least not enough correct from a a mathematical point of view (I'm not mathematician), let me change it to:

I think following code can help

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document} 
%\begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty,
            xlabel={$t$},xlabel style={anchor=east},
            ylabel={$f(x)=x^{2/3}$},ylabel style={anchor=north}]
            \addplot[-] expression[domain=-1:1,samples=1000]{(x^2)^(1/3)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
%\end{subfigure}
%\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Original sentence**:x^(2/3) = (x^2)^(1/3) which seems to work

Comment: `x^(2/3)`  is not equal to  `(x^2)^(1/3)`! If this was true, `sqrt(-1)=(-1)^(1/2)=((-1)^2)^(1/4)=(1)^(1/4)=1`. (The result may well be what the OP wanted to get, in which case you can plot `abs(x)^(2/3)`, but mathematically your statement is nonsense.)

Comment: @user231225 you are incorrect. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1628759/what-are-the-laws-of-rational-exponents) for typical textbook. It says if x^(m/n)=(x^m)^(1/n) provided m and n have no common factors, n>1
and x^(1/n) is a real number. Since 2 and 3 have no common factor, and x^(1/3) is a real number for all x, Ignasi is correct. If 
this was not correct then you would need to find a counterexample: a value of x for which x^(2/3) is not equal to (x^2)^(1/3). Your argument only
demonstrates that x^(2/4) is not equal to (x^2)^(1/4).

Comment: @DJP No, you are incorrect. `x^a` is defined to be `\exp(a \ln(x))`. The logarithm has several branches. Please do me a favor and look in a text book. Or just compute some negative number raised to a fractional exponent.

Comment: We aren't talking about complex numbers and different branches we're dealing with the Cartesian plane as is clear from the plots. I linked you to a text book definition for real numbers. If I'm wrong then you would need to find a counterexample: a value of x for which x^(2/3) is not equal to (x^2)^(1/3). Since the cube root has domain of all real numbers, that's unlikely.

Comment: @user231225 "([...] but mathematically your statement is nonsense.)". That is not true. It is false, as I have gathered from a quick hop into Desmos. `x^{2/3}` and `(x^2)^(1/3)` is infact equal (at least in this context). I am also unsure what you mean by "*real*" mathematicians.

Comment: @Concerto Again, `x^a=\exp(a \ln(x))`, believe it or not. If you want to define a fractional exponent for a negative number, you have to specify the branch of the logarithm. `x^(2/3) = (x^2)^(1/3)` is just **wrong**.

Comment: @user231225 I'll go into your reply after you've went into mine. Because my knowledge is limited, I'd like to know, why Desmos should be wrong?

Comment: @Concerto I do not know Desmos, but I have attended some math classes.And if you do not want to believe me, fine, maybe you want to look the example at the end of [this Wikipedia section on Rational exponents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Rational_exponents). (No, I am not claiming that Wikipedia is always right.) But really any math book on elementary calculus should have this information: you cannot just manipulate the fractional numbers of negative (or complex) numbers in this way. In general, this will lead to wrong results.

Comment: Note that 1^(1/3) has three solutions: 1, -0.5+0.866i and -0.5-0.866i.  Similarly, (x*x)^(1/3) is the real valued solution for x^(2/3).

Comment: @user231225 Desmos is a graphing calculator -> desmos.com

Comment: So, what is the mathematical conclusion?: Same or different functions?

Comment: A function needs domain/range.If domain/range reals then plot is 2 dimensional (x,y).If domain reals,range complex then plot is 3 dimensional (x,(a,b)) where a+bi is the complex answer.If domain/range in complex,4 dimensional.Difficult to plot on 2 dimensional screen.user231225 is saying with 3 complex solutions to cube root any 1 can be answer.OP was looking for 2 dimensional plot hence real answer expected.Same real valued functions.